# show variables - Unknown column 'value' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

In mysql I ran the below:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES where variable_name = 'character_set_database';
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| character_set_database | utf8  |
+------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.32 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES where variable_name = 'character_set_database' and value = 'utf8';
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'value' in 'where clause'
```

Why does the above happen?

Comment: Can you check out once again. Really you are getting such error. I am sure you are doing some mistake.

Comment: No..its not a mistake.  I am getting that result.  Thats the ouptut.

Answer (score 1):

`SHOW` does not have that syntax.  Simply do

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_database';
```

and don't include the 'value'.

Answer (score 0):

@Tampa, As you said getting error after executing this query.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES where variable_name = 'character_set_database' and value = 'utf8';
```

And Error is like that **`ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'value' in 'where clause'.`**

As mention your both query command executing successfully. For your ref i am attaching snapshot 
[image]

Really if you are sure to getting such mention error .

As of **@Drew** has well explained in very well you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32159465/error-1054-42s22-unknown-column-marks-in-field-list.

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, it is better to use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

```
mysql> desc information_schema.global_variables;
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| VARIABLE_NAME  | varchar(64)   | NO   |     |         |       |
| VARIABLE_VALUE | varchar(1024) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

With this you can use straight SQL

```
select * from information_schema.global_variables
where variable_name = 'character_set_database';
```

In some instances, certain variables were moved to performance_schema. You could search MySQL Documentation on other variables or just restart mysqld with [show_compatibility_56](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_show_compatibility_56) enabled.